# CoCreateInstance returns E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, winapi, go, cgo, wpd

I have been working on wrapping WindowsPortableDevice Api for Golang. The c++ code below was working but suddenly is not working.

libgowpd.h:

```
#include <Windows.h>

typedef struct IPortableDeviceManager IPortableDeviceManager;

HRESULT createPortableDeviceManager(IPortableDeviceManager **pPortableDeviceManager);
```

libgowpd.cpp:

```
#include <libgowpd.h>

HRESULT createPortableDeviceManager(IPortableDeviceManager **pPortableDeviceManager) {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PortableDeviceManager,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(pPortableDeviceManager));
    }

    return hr;
}
```

In Golang

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -blahblah
#cgo LDFLAGS: -llibgowpd -Ole32

include "libgowpd.h"
*/
import "C"

type HRESULT uint64
type IPortableDeviceManager C.IPortableDeviceManager

func CreatePortableDeviceManager() (*IPortableDeviceManager, error) {
    var pPortableDeviceManager *C.struct_IPortableDeviceManager// No matter whether C.IPortableDeviceManager or C.struct_IPortableDeviceManager

    hr := C.createPortableDeviceManager(&pPortableDeviceManager)

    if hr < 0 {
        return nil, HRESULT(hr)
    }
    if pPortableDeviceManager == nil {
        return nil, E_POINTER
    }

    log.Println("CreatePortableDeviceManager(): Create portable device manager instance.")

    return (*IPortableDeviceManager)(pPortableDeviceManager), nil
}
```

I think I pass pointer to `pPortableDeviceManager` correctly via getting address of `pPortableDeviceManager` but it returns `0x80070057` error code(`E_INVALIDARG`).

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for [CoInitializeEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx). The way you are using it is unusual to say the least. And probably wrong. Don't try to initialize COM from your library. Have clients of your library initialize COM on the calling thread.

Comment: I removed init code in cpp and written the code in Golang. (`hr := C.CoInitializeEx(nil, C.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)`) And this code returns S_OK but problem still remains.

Comment: Not so easy to see whether the -blahblah compile option takes care of the proper calling convention.  HRESULT is a 32-bit type.

Comment: @HansPassant -blahblah is just include options to find `libgowpd.h` file. And I don't know why but when I try to cast `C.E_SOMEERROR` to `uint32`, go compiler throws overflow error.

Comment: `HRESULT`'s are signed 32-bit values. Your code doesn't appear to acknowledge this.

Comment: the `E_INVALIDARG` can be or when *pPortableDeviceManager* == 0 or when *dwClsContext* is invalid. simply look in debugger parameters in call `CoCreateInstance`

Comment: @RbMm `IID_PPV_ARGS` macro couldn't get `IID` of pointer. So the problem was `dwClsContext`. I manually set parameter so that I could solve the problem. Thank you all!